# assign an ArrayList to a List in java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, junit

I am implementing the code that can considering the following junit test:

```
package it.unica.pr2.pizze.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;
import java.util.*; 
import it.unica.pr2.pizze.*; 

@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class TestPizza {

  @Test
    public void test1() {
      Ingrediente mozzarella = new Ingrediente("mozzarella",50);
      Ingrediente pomodoro = new Ingrediente("pomodoro",10);
      Ingrediente[] ingredienti = new Ingrediente[] {mozzarella, pomodoro}
      Pizza pizzaMargherita = new Pizza(ingredienti);
      assertTrue( pizzaMargherita.calorie() == 60 );
      List ingredientiMargherita = pizzaMargherita;
        assertTrue(ingredientiMargherita.size() ==2);
        assertTrue(ingredientiMargherita.get(0) == mozzarella);
        assertTrue(ingredientiMargherita.get(1) == pomodoro);
     }
```

and here is my classe: Pizza

```
package it.unica.pr2.pizze;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Pizza  {


    private ArrayList<Ingrediente> ingredienti;


    public Pizza(Ingrediente[] ing) {

        this.ingredienti = new ArrayList<>();

        int i = 0;
        while (i < ing.length) {

            this.ingredienti.add(ing[i]);
            i++;
        }

    }

    public double calorie(){

        double sumaCalorie = 0;

        for(Ingrediente elem: this.ingredienti)
            sumaCalorie += elem.getCalorie();

        return sumaCalorie;

    }
}
```

and an other class: Ingrediente

```
package it.unica.pr2.pizze;


public class Ingrediente  {


    private String nomeIngrediente;
    private double calorie;



    public Ingrediente(String nomeIngrediente, double calorie) throws IngredienteNonValidoException {

        this.nomeIngrediente = nomeIngrediente;
        if (calorie < 0) throw new IngredienteNonValidoException();
        else
            this.calorie = calorie;
    }

    public void setNomeIng(String nomeIngrediente) {
        this.nomeIngrediente = nomeIngrediente;
    }

    public void setCalorie(double calorie) {

        this.calorie = calorie;
    }

    public String getNomeIng() {

        return this.nomeIngrediente;
    }

    public double getCalorie() {
        return this.calorie;
    }

}
```

After running the test I got the following error:

`error: incompatible types: Pizza cannot be converted to List`

`List ingredientiMargherita = pizzaMargherita;`

So I don't know how to convert an ArrayList into a List just using the operator  =, I can not modify the junit test code.

Comment: I am 99% sure the unit test code has an error in it. If this was an assignment, go back to your professor and ask if they really meant the line "List ingredientiMargherita = pizzaMargherita;" rather than "List ingredientiMargherita = pizzaMargherita.getIngrediente();". Otherwise the only solution is markspace's.

Comment: Yes, the test code is rather suspect.  I would verify that it's not mistaken. Requiring a value class like Pizza to implement List is kinda weird.

Comment: Either that or what OP has tried to re-write to run the program.

Comment: no error in the unit test, the solution i found is here below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a solution without editing the junit test code, i had to modify my Pizza.java as follows:

```
package it.unica.pr2.pizze;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;

public class Pizza extends ArrayList   {

    public Pizza(Ingrediente[] ing) {

        for(Ingrediente elem: ing) {

            this.add(elem);
        }

    }

    public int calorie() {
        int calorie = 0;
        for(Object i : this) {
            calorie += ((Ingrediente)i).getCalorie();
        }
        return calorie;
    }


}
```

now the test is passed correctly.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't modify the assignment, you have to do this:

```
public class Pizza implements List {
...
}
```

Or something equivalent, like

```
public class Pizza extends AbstractList {
...
}
```

Comment: From a design point of view this is a terrible solution. But it's the only one that could work. +1.

Comment: Yeah, I know, it's kinda ugly.  I think your comment about the test case likely being a typo is probably worth it for the OP to check.

Comment: And no criticism intended, in case you took it that way. Just wanted to make sure that people didn't try doing this where they didn't have to.

Answer (score 1):

On below line in your unit test you are assigning `Pizza` type to a `List`:

```
List ingredientiMargherita = pizzaMargherita;
```

Change it to something like:

```
List<Ingrediente> ingredientiMargherita = pizzaMargherita.getIngredienti();
```

And add a `getIngredienti()` to return `List` in your `Pizza` class:

```
public ArrayList<Ingrediente> getIngredienti(){
     return ingredienti;
}
```

Comment: This also works, but when the OP said he/she couldn't modify the assignment, I assumed a modification to the test code like this was not possible.  If it is possible, this is likely the better solution.